# Как на Tkinter python поменять значение виджета Text через Combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Допустим у меня есть один виджет text и два виджета Combobox, как мне сделать так, чтобы виджет text постоянно менялся в соответствии с выбранным вариантом из обоих Combobox, например :

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()

Combo1 = Combobox(root)
Combo1['values'] = (1, 2)
Combo1.pack()

Combo2 = Combobox(root)
Combo2['values'] = [3, 4]
Combo2.pack()

text = Text(root)# Этот виджет должен меняться в соответствии
text.pack()# с Combo1 и Combo 2

root.mainloop()
```

Нужно чтобы в Text был и вариант из Combo1 и из Combo2
И цикл пробовал, но при использовании цикла код просто уходил в бесконечнй цикл

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации подобной задачи нужно забиндить (`bind`) комобобоксы на обработчики обновления при событии `ComboboxSelected`, ну и разумеется понадобится где-то хранить данные в данном случае это словарь `data`, для вывода можно использовать одну и ту же функцию так как элемент вывода один и тот же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

root = Tk()

Combo1 = Combobox(root)
Combo1['values'] = (1, 2)
Combo1.pack()

Combo2 = Combobox(root)
Combo2['values'] = [3, 4]
Combo2.pack()

text = Text(root)# Этот виджет должен меняться в соответствии
text.pack()# с Combo1 и Combo 2

data = {
  "value1" :"",
  "value2" :""
}

def setText():
  global data
  text.delete("0.0", "end")
  text.insert(INSERT, 
    f'''значение1: {data['value1']}
значение2: {data['value2']}''')

def update1(event):
  global data
  data["value1"] = event.widget.get()
  setText()

def update2(event):
  global data
  data["value2"] = event.widget.get()
  setText()

Combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update1)
Combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update2)

root.mainloop()
```